# How to give padding to Table tag in Bootstrap?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

In my projects that I use twitter bootstrap some times I need to give padding or margin to a `Table` tag .
So I code something like this :

```css
#table-parent {
    padding-top: 50px;     /* <---- Padding that moved down the hole Table */
}


td {                                          /*****************************/
    padding: 10px;                            /*****************************/
    text-align: center;                       /**** JUST THE CSS STYLES ****/
    border-left: 1px #575757 solid;           /****    NOT IMPORTANT    ****/
    border-right: 1px #575757 solid;          /*****************************/
}                                             /*****************************/
                                              /****       OPTIONAL      ****/
                                              /*****************************/
tr:nth-child(1) {                             /*****************************/
    background: silver;                       /*****************************/
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div id="table-parent">
    <table class="table table-striped">
        <tr>
            <td>Title 1</td>
            <td>Title 2</td>
            <td>Title 3</td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td>Value A</td>
            <td>Value B</td>
            <td>Value C</td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td>Value AA</td>
            <td>Value BB</td>
            <td>Value CC</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

You see I padding the `div` that is the parent of `table` .
But I don't like this ...
I want to give padding directly to the `table` tag . Something like this :

```css
table {
  padding-top: 50px;
}



td {                                          /*****************************/
    padding: 10px;                            /*****************************/
    text-align: center;                       /**** JUST THE CSS STYLES ****/
    border-left: 1px #575757 solid;           /****    NOT IMPORTANT    ****/
    border-right: 1px #575757 solid;          /*****************************/
}                                             /*****************************/
                                              /****       OPTIONAL      ****/
                                              /*****************************/
tr:nth-child(1) {                             /*****************************/
    background: silver;                       /*****************************/
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<table class="table table-striped">
    <tr>
        <td>Title 1</td>
        <td>Title 2</td>
        <td>Title 3</td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td>Value A</td>
        <td>Value B</td>
        <td>Value C</td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td>Value AA</td>
        <td>Value BB</td>
        <td>Value CC</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

But this isn't working . Can you help ?

Comment: Try `margin-top`

Answer (score 2):

if you want to use `padding` for a `table` you should set `border-collapse: separate;` on it.

```css
table {
  padding-top: 50px;
  border-collapse: separate!important;
}



td {                                          /*****************************/
    padding: 10px;                            /*****************************/
    text-align: center;                       /**** JUST THE CSS STYLES ****/
    border-left: 1px #575757 solid;           /****    NOT IMPORTANT    ****/
    border-right: 1px #575757 solid;          /*****************************/
}                                             /*****************************/
                                              /****       OPTIONAL      ****/
                                              /*****************************/
tr:nth-child(1) {                             /*****************************/
    background: silver;                       /*****************************/
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<table class="table table-striped">
    <tr>
        <td>Title 1</td>
        <td>Title 2</td>
        <td>Title 3</td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td>Value A</td>
        <td>Value B</td>
        <td>Value C</td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td>Value AA</td>
        <td>Value BB</td>
        <td>Value CC</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `margin-top: 50px;` instead of `padding-top: 50px;`

```css
table {
  margin-top: 50px;
}



td {                                          /*****************************/
    padding: 10px;                            /*****************************/
    text-align: center;                       /**** JUST THE CSS STYLES ****/
    border-left: 1px #575757 solid;           /****    NOT IMPORTANT    ****/
    border-right: 1px #575757 solid;          /*****************************/
}                                             /*****************************/
                                              /****       OPTIONAL      ****/
                                              /*****************************/
tr:nth-child(1) {                             /*****************************/
    background: silver;                       /*****************************/
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<table class="table table-striped">
    <tr>
        <td>Title 1</td>
        <td>Title 2</td>
        <td>Title 3</td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td>Value A</td>
        <td>Value B</td>
        <td>Value C</td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td>Value AA</td>
        <td>Value BB</td>
        <td>Value CC</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: I know I can add margin . But In my full project if I add margin to table the hole page will be destroy .

Comment: then its better to add a class to table and then use margin.

Comment: No I mean margin will destroy other blocks